# How to attach or include user identity (username or email address) in the JWT token while using Client Credential Grant Flow

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

We are using azure AD. While using the Client Credential grant flow, how do i attach an user's identity (username and/or email address) to the JWT token that is generated using the Client Credential grant flow?

My API will extract user email address from the token and use it. The consumers of the API are mostly automation scripts which require almost no user interaction such as the user has to respond interactively to the authentication popup keying in their username and password.

I also am aware that OAuth 2 resource owner password credentials (ROPC) grant is an option but it is discouraged from using by microsoft documentation.

thanks!

Comment: Client credentials flow is used by applications to call APIs without a user context. Since there is no user involved, there won't be user claims in the token. The API should be made to support app-only callers by defining an application permission (app role) on the API app registration, and allow callers with that permission to define the user email in the request instead of getting it from the token. If you want a token with user info, you will need to use a flow like authorization code / device code / refresh token.

Comment: It would help if you described the scenario a bit more. Where are these scripts running? Could bootstrapping be done by a user and then the script could use refresh tokens to call the API as that user?

Comment: As @juunas indicated, Client credentials flow is used by applications to call APIs without a user context. For your scenario, how about using on-behalf-of flow?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

Comment: It's correct. Client Credential grant flow generates an Application token rather than a user token. Application token won't include user identity.

Comment: Do you still need help on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Summarize from the comments above:

Client credential flow is used by applications to call APIs without user context, so the token doesn't contain user context. If you want the token with user info, I suggest you to use authorization code flow, ROPC flow or any other grant flow.